# Problems connecting to github using ssh

Tags: git, github

I have a problem using `ssh` to connect to github.

I have a remote configured in my project, I see it using `git remote -v`.

When I execute the command `git push origin master`

The error is:

```
$ git push origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In future add error messages to the question as text not an image. What does `git remote -v` show?

Comment: We need the output of git remote -v ( If you wont show ups, just changes names etc and fake it, but we must know what appear ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add authentication keys to your git account.

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### Adding ssh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Generate KEY

```
- cd   ~/.ssh

- ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@email.com"
```

NOTE - 
Keys need to be only readable by you:

chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

If Keys need to be read-writable by you:

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Step 2: Check the Contents and copy

```
- cat ~/.ssh/nameOfFile.pub | pbcopy
```

Step 3: Configure your SSH key into Bitbucket.org (similar applies to Github.com) 
GOTO settings => SSHKEY

```
- Add what you copied in Step 2 and give it a name
```

Step 4:  Clone your repository using SSH protocol

```
- git clone git@bitbucket.org:{username}/repo.git

- git clone git@github.com:{username}/repo.git
```

This should work BUT

If you keep getting this error

[
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

]

Follow this steps.

```
i. ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org OR ssh -T hg@github.com depending on which you are using { This will attempt to create a connection to Bitbucket OR Github Cloud ).

ii. If you do not see a message similar  to (logged in as username.). Go to the next step

iii. ssh-add ~/.ssh/identity (identity is whatever name you saved the file when generating a key)

iv. You will get this message (Identity added: /path to ssh file/.ssh/mywork (youremail@email.com)
v. You can now clone your repository.
```